# HDD is not recognized correctly

Tags: hard-drive

I have got a WD black HDD (WD1002FBYS), i want to connect it to my laptop through an adapter SATA->USB but cant make it work, it spins when i connect it then stops, i tried to restart the laptop it hangs for about 5 minutes on POST then boots, but the drive still doesn't work. maybe dmesg output will be helpful:

```
[ 2006.066073] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[ 2006.096717] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=0578, bcdDevice=32.02
[ 2006.096718] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2006.096719] usb 2-1: Product: JMS579
[ 2006.096720] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: JMicron
[ 2006.096721] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 5002627380546588
[ 2006.100029] scsi host2: uas
**[ 2006.100552] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     KINGSTON  SA400S37480G    3202 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6**
[ 2006.102001] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
```

then after a while:

```
[ 2119.042929] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 2119.042935] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[ 2119.042938] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
[ 2125.060566] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 2125.060572] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[ 2125.060575] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
[ 2125.061233] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[ 2125.061237] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 0-byte physical blocks
[ 2131.078206] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
[ 2133.084031] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[ 2133.084038] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 2139.101680] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (0 bytes)
[ 2139.107485] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
```

I noticed **KINGSTON  SA400S37480G**, why does it show KINGSTON it is a WD drive, the KINGSTON device it shows is another SSD drive i had connected previously...

lsblk doesn't list the device.
lsusb shows `Bus 002 Device 006: ID 152d:0578 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. JMS567 SATA 6Gb/s bridge` if that makes sense.

am not hardware guru so excuse me if i asked a silly question, thanks.

BTW I already tried to connect through SATA to home PC, it throws an error on boot saying **secondary master hard disk error**...

Comment: That drive could be near 10 years old. It could genuinely be faulty.

Comment: It is possible that there is not enough power provided by USB port.

Comment: WD1002FBYS is a 3.5" drive, and would require an external power source.  The USB host is incapable of powering a 3.5" HDD.

Comment: The connector i used has a power connector, the disk doesn't spin without it, i also tried connecting it to a desktop PC through SATA.. the same problem remains.. @sawdust